# Visual Basic Studio 2010 does not start

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I've got trouble with my copy of Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express.

I installed it about a year ago. Since then I've used it several times without any problems. Now, I haven't used it for some weeks and now, when I try to start the application, it crashes after the welcome-screen with a not-helpful message. Because I use the german version of Visual Studio, I don't know exactly, how this message would look like in english:

German: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht.
English (freely translated): A called target has caused an exception.

So, as you see, this Error Screen does not give many information. It is also not possible to gather more information. After clicking OK to the error, the application simply shuts down.

Some details

- I am using the german installation of MS Visual Basic 2010 Express
- I've got also installed the german version of MS Visual C++ 2010 Express (does not work as well)
- Both applications does not work with user permissions nor with administrator permissions
- No possible Compatibility-Option (Compatibility Mode, Reduced Color Mode, etc) fix the problem
- I work inside a physical Windows 8.1 machine
- I installed all updates, that came with the automated update feature of windows
- I've got another copy of MS Studio Express inside a VM (Windows 7), working properly
- I do not remember exactly what I have changed since my last use of VS, I think I installed Far Cry 4 AFTER my last use, wich came with some .NET components. But I don't think there were other big changes inside the system.

Because the error message is so inconcrete, I do not know, wich further information can be useful, nor I can imagine any problem, that suddenly occured. So I hope somebody got a similar problem and knows how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to go for visual studio community 2013.It's free and you can recover your previous work.
You can download it here.

[http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517284][1]

Even if you find an error go to build->clean solution.It will work like wonder.

thanks
N S Deo